Drop-pin symbol without using fontawesome5
I want to add the following drop-pin symbol to my resume against my address.

Is there a way to do this without using the fontawesome5 package (whose .sty file either doesn't compile or keeps throwing other errors on my system).
Also, is there a way to get symbols for the weblink, telephone receiver, and black envelope similarly?



The wasysym package's \phone command renders an older phone image. I want only the black receiver symbol. Similarly, marvosym package's \Letter command yields a white envelope.

If you're experiencing an issue including font-related stuff, here's what you can do: Compile a standalone document with a single symbol in it. The result is a PDF of just that symbol that you can include as an image in another document. Do this for whatever symbols you need.
